# SSL Handshake Failure using self signed certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https

So i am trying to connect to 1 server which is SSL enabled using self signed certificates. Which connecting to it,I am getting this.
Can someone help in this? These are the SSL logs.
And in java code, i am ignoring any certificate issues.

```
UTC|ClientHello.java:575|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "F4 2B A6 C1 29 C8 77 C3 88 38 42 91 19 98 CC 54 F7 5E A5 02 60 09 76 3B A6 23 85 DC D2 8B CA 51",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=performance.infoworks.technology
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01 08|WRAPPER-ReplId-1153a-95ac1-f8ba4-7|2022-08-23 10:19:26.352 UTC|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|SEVERE|01 08|WRAPPER-ReplId-1153a-95ac1-f8ba4-7|2022-08-23 10:19:26.353 UTC|TransportContext.java:340|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:335)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:185)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:156)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:439)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:410)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
```

Comment: Except a few cases like missing or wrong SNI, it is pretty much impossible to diagnose first-flight alert 40 from the client side. **Look at the server log(s) to see what the server thinks is wrong.** This alert can happen because the server config is bad, but the details vary depending on what software and middleware the server is running. Is there a reason you're using a TLS1.3-capable version of Java but disabling TLS1.3? That's not prohibited, but it's quite odd.

Answer (score -2):

Using a browser to access `https://performance.infoworks.technology` and checking the certificate confirms that the certificate is not trusted.

It is signed by an issuer which is not trusted: `IW Root CA`.

You need to make `IW Root CA` available on the client, put it into the certificate storage which is used in the context of running your java application to make sure is trusted at the time the request is made.

Alternatively, for testing only (!), you can disable the certificate validation when making the request.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for pointing that out, i edited the answer to read "is not trusted" instead of "is self signed".